# STUFF() function in sql server for Blank Space in row column

Tags: sql, sql-server

This is my Query, it is working well but when ever there is a  row with null values the stuff function does not serve my requirements. any alternative way to do that ? 
(eg : For NUll values phone Number  looks like  ,464-987-987)

```
 SELECT 
     smsFDGPatientOrder.ID,
    STUFF((SELECT ', ' + [smsFDGPatientOrderPhoneNumbers].Number 
               FROM [smsFDGPatientOrderPhoneNumbers] 
               WHERE [smsFDGPatientOrderPhoneNumbers].FDGPatientOrder = smsFDGPatientOrder.ID
              ORDER BY Number
               FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 1, '') [PatientPhno]
     FROM smsFDGPatientOrder
    GROUP BY smsFDGPatientOrder.ID
```

Sample Data For Which not working

```
 ID     Name    Number          FDGPatientOrder Type    Index
189950  Home    630-561-3777    170638          1       NULL
189951  Home                    170638          1       NULL
```

Comment: `SELECT ... WHERE Number IS NOT NULL` would simply not select the NULL numbers... Seems like what you should be doing.

Comment: @TT yea right. but  WHERE Number <> LTRIM('') it would be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `COALESCE` to replace `NULL` values with the default, i.e. `'464-987-987'`:

```
SELECT smsFDGPatientOrder.ID,
       STUFF((SELECT ', ' + COALESCE(s.Number, '464-987-987') 
              FROM [smsFDGPatientOrderPhoneNumbers] AS s
              WHERE s.FDGPatientOrder = smsFDGPatientOrder.ID
              ORDER BY Number
              FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 1, '') [PatientPhno]
FROM smsFDGPatientOrder
GROUP BY smsFDGPatientOrder.ID
```

**Edit:**

In case the problem is due to a non existent matching record in `smsFDGPatientOrderPhoneNumbers` you can use:

```
SELECT smsFDGPatientOrder.ID,
       COALESCE(
          STUFF((SELECT ', ' + s.Number
               FROM [smsFDGPatientOrderPhoneNumbers] AS s
               WHERE s.FDGPatientOrder = smsFDGPatientOrder.ID
               ORDER BY Number
               FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 1, ''),
          '464-987-987')) [PatientPhno]
FROM smsFDGPatientOrder
GROUP BY smsFDGPatientOrder.ID
```

**Edit2:**

To handle space or empty string values you can use:

```
SELECT smsFDGPatientOrder.ID,
       STUFF((SELECT ', ' + s.Number
               FROM [smsFDGPatientOrderPhoneNumbers] AS s
               WHERE s.FDGPatientOrder = smsFDGPatientOrder.ID AND
                     LTRIM(s.Number) <> ''
               ORDER BY Number
               FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 1, '') [PatientPhno]
FROM smsFDGPatientOrder
GROUP BY smsFDGPatientOrder.ID
```

Comment: Not Working with COALESCE and why should i put the hard coded '464-987-987'

Comment: I think the OP does not actually mean a `null` in `smsFDGPatientOrderPhoneNumbers.number` but rather no row. Therefore the coalesce should be outside the `stuff`.

Comment: @SouravMukherjee In this case some sample data would help to elucidate the problem.

Comment: Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 3
Incorrect syntax near 'STUFF'.
Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 6
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'ORDER'.

For EDITED QUERY getting ERROR

Comment: @GiorgosBetsos still not working .. i have added the sample data for which it is not working ... see the question section. Actually There is blank Space. sorry for my bad.

Comment: Why you are adding hard Coded '464-987-987' . i should not add any number for '',

Comment: @GiorgosBetsos  AND LTRIM(s.Number) = '' made all rows NULL result.

Comment: @SouravMukherjee Sorry, it should be  `AND LTRIM(s.Number) <> ''`

Comment: WHERE Number <> LTRIM('') Worked Finally... really a small mistake ! Thanks For The Help Btw